# NodeJS request through NTLM authentication

Tags: node.js, request, ntlm

in  a corporate environment I am trying to crawl a web application. I have to access it through a proxy running on CNTLM.

I tried these libraries - request-ntlm and httpntlm. After fixing some small issues with the libraries, I finally got a result saying the credentials are not valid.

This is my entire (not working) solution:

```
var ntlm = require('request-ntlm');

var opts = {
  username: 'myaccount-clean text',
  password: 'mypassword-clean text',
  _domain: 'mydomain-clean text',
  workstation: '',
  url: 'https://web i am trying to access that requires ntlm',
  proxy: "http://127.0.0.1:3128"
};
var json = {
  // whatever object you want to submit 
};
ntlm.get(opts, json, function(err, response) {
   if ( err ) {
    console.log( err );
   }
   else {
       console.log( response );
   }
});
```

PS: If u run into trouble compiling the request-ntlm, just replace options.domain in the ntlm.js and index.js file with _domain.

Comment: My collegue seems to be able to get it working with a python library, really wanna beat him to it :)